# Spring-Integration: "Dispatcher has no subscribers" if log is last step

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have the trivial Spring IntegrationFlow as below which is giving me `org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers`.

This seems to be related to the Flow´s last step which is a `log` step. If I either remove the `log` step or put another identity transformation after that step the `Dispatcher has no subscribers` is not thrown.

I´d like to understand what is the problem with having `log` as last step.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args)) {
            final Gateway gateway = ctx.getBean(Gateway.class);
            final String rs = gateway.send("hello");
            System.out.println(rs);

        }
    }

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "flow.input")
    public interface Gateway {
        String send(String msg);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow() {
        return f -> f
                .transform((String p) -> p + ", world")
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO, "kljkh"); // throws Dispatcher has no subscribers 
    }
}
```

Following two options work, but why not the one with `log` as last step?

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return f -> f
            .transform((String p) -> p + ", world")
            .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO, "kljkh")
            .transform(Function.identity()); // works
}
```

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return f -> f
            .transform((String p) -> p + ", world"); // works
}
```

Comment: So I guess this is because `log` is a wiretap acting as an interceptor on a channel and not an endpoint...

Comment: Yes, it's a wire tap - fixed in Spring Integration 5 - see my answer for a work around.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41695292/httprequestexecutingmessagehandler-no-output-channel-or-replychannel-header-ava/41699176#41699176).

Log is a wiretap. In the upcoming Spring Integration 5.0, we allow `.log()` to be a final element in a flow.

The workaround is to add `.channel("nullChannel")` after a final `log()`.